# Compare same column's data in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to compare the same column's data based on another row. Suppose I have table which shows details like the below:

| Username | Service | Privilege |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Test | Audit |
| XYZ | Test 1 | Maintain |
| XYZ | Test 1 | Manage |
| XYZ | Test 1 | Audit |

And I want result like:

| Username | Service | Privilege |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | Test 1 | Maintain |
| XYZ | Test 1 | Manage |

Basically, I want to remove all privileges which are used in more than one service like here audit privilege was used in both Tests as well as in Test 1 service.

How can I achieve this solution using Oracle SQL?

Comment: Do you need to delete the data permanently, or do you just want to exclude the 'Audit' rows from the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Sample data in lines #1 - 6; query begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with test (username, service, privilege) as
  2    (select 'ABC', 'Test' , 'Audit'    from dual union all
  3     select 'XYZ', 'Test1', 'Maintain' from dual union all
  4     select 'XYZ', 'Test1', 'Manage'   from dual union all
  5     select 'XYZ', 'Test1', 'Audit'    from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where privilege not in (select privilege
 10                          from test
 11                          group by privilege
 12                          having count(*) > 1);

USE SERVI PRIVILEG
--- ----- --------
XYZ Test1 Maintain
XYZ Test1 Manage

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a delete with a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.Privilege = t1.Privilege AND t2.Service <> t1.Service);
```

The above query, read in plain English, says to delete any privilege record for which we can find the same privilege associated with a different service.

Comment: @ChrisPop . . . This better answers the question that you actually asked.  Your question leaves open the possibility that there could be multiple privileges with the *same* service.  And this is probably faster than the version with aggregation in the subquery.